# jquery Intellisense não funciona no VS2015 Community

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Não consigo fazer funcionar de jeito nenhum.

Meu `_references.js`

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.mask.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.intellisense.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.matchmedia.addlistener.min.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.min.js" />
```

Porém, quando estou na *View* fazendo algum código jQuery o *intellisense* não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Experimente fechar e reabrir o Visual Studio.

Comment: Cigano, ja reinstalei essa coisa... hehe

Comment: E ainda não funcionou?

Comment: Nada... quando digito $('Document') e aperto "." (ponto) nada acontece... e do mesmo jeito para qualquer tipo de codigo javascript... tentei algumas configuracoes que o pessoal mostrou mas nada de funcionar...

Comment: Experimenta um `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /updateconfiguration` e depois `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /clearcache`.

Comment: xara, vc eh bom mesmo... obrigado cara... funcionou!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possivelmente você atualizou alguma coisa e a *cache* se perdeu. Execute os seguintes passos:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /updateconfiguration
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /clearcache
```